# Getting exception while running SaltStack module.run function with name dsc.apply_config

Tags: windows, salt-stack, dsc

I'm getting the following error while trying to state.apply sls on windows machine.

> ```
>       ID: ProvisionADDC
> Function: module.run
>     Name: dsc.apply_config
>   Result: False
>  Comment: Module function dsc.apply_config threw an exception. Exception: No JSON results from powershell. Additional info follows:
>
>          retcode:
>               0
>           stderr:
>           stdout:
> Started: 12:06:08.044000
> Duration: 2684.0 ms
>  Changes:
> ```

Since win_dsc is execution module, then I'm forced to use state.module module to run this function on minion:

```
C:\DSC:
  file.directory:
    - makedirs: True

allprofiles:
   win_firewall.disabled

CopyDSCModules:
  file.recurse:
    - name: 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'
    - source: salt://windows/dsc/

InstallADDomainServices:
   win_servermanager.installed:
     - name: AD-Domain-Services
     - restart: True
     - require:
       - file: CopyDSCModules

ProvisionADDC:
   module.run:
     - name: dsc.apply_config
     - path: C:\DSC\
     - source: salt://windows/mof
     - require:
       - file: 'C:\DSC'
       - file: CopyDSCModules
       - win_servermanager: InstallADDomainServices
```

Anybody have experience with win_dsc and SaltStack ?

Comment: did you ever get a complete working example of this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a case of the documentation lacking a bit, but you need to actually run the configuration in the same ps1 file, eg.

```
Configuration myconfig {
    Node 'localhost' {
        WindowsFeature 'DNS' {
            Name = 'DNS'
            Ensure = Present
        }
    }
}

myconfig
```

I'm playing with this a litle at the moment and hopefully I can come up with a helpful issue/PR because it is lacking a bit (even if just for better error logging).

I'm not sure how this works in terms of determining a specific config as I'e not tested that yet (using the `config_name` param).